# How to Capture Google Analytics User ID & Insert into SQL DataBase for Backend Lead Qualifying

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want to capture Google Analytics User IDs into our company's SQL database WITH the following information: UTM_Source / UTM_Campaign / UTM_Keyword / Goal Completion.

I know some analytis services may be better equipped but I believe there is a way to hack this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write User IDs to a custom dimension (session or user scope, as you need).
For each User ID and UTMs set you will see a number of Goal Completions.
Using [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide) you can import these reports into your DB:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A89723405&start-date=yesterday&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3AgoalCompletionsAll&dimensions=ga%3Adimension1%2Cga%3Asource%2Cga%3Acampaign%2Cga%3Akeyword
```

Comment: How would i go about tying the Google Analytics User IDs to the emails stored in the DB?